# How the first activity get data of the second activity but only when return of this second one

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am a new in the android and java universe, but i have project that i have construct a app like a "Tip Calculator".

The guides for this project are:

> Write an app that will have two activities.
>
> FIRST ACTIVITY
>
> 1. Label "Meal Amount", "Tax", "Tip", "Total" and corresponding text views
> 2. User can enter meal amount
> 3. Tax, tip and total are calculated (Note: you may need to set certain property to make these TextViews read only)
> 4. There is a button called "Calculate" that when pressed will spawn the SECOND ACTIVITY
> 5. Once the calculations are done, display the amounts
>
> SECOND ACTIVITY
>
> 1. Label "Tax Percentage" and corresponding TextView where the user will enter the tax percentage
> 2. Buttons denoting service quality "Poor 8%", "Average 10%", "Good 15%", and "Outstanding 20%"
> 3. When one of these buttons is pressed, the app needs to calculate the required amounts and pass the results back to the FIRST ACTIVITY

My problem is when i start the first activity and i need do a function that run only when return from the second activity and no when start the application. But i can't do.

Below I pasted my code of the first and second activity.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.viniciuscardoso.tipcalculator;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public Button mCalculateButton;
    public double Tax = 7;
    public double Tip = 10;
    public TextView TextViewTax;
    public TextView TextViewTip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextViewTax  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewTax);
        TextViewTip  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewTip);
        mCalculateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        TextViewTax.setText(String.valueOf(Tax));
        TextViewTip.setText(String.valueOf(Tip));

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTip.class);

        mCalculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

ActivityTip.java

```
package com.example.viniciuscardoso.tipcalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class ActivityTip extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button mPoorButton;
    Button mAverageButton;
    Button mGoodButton;
    Button mOutstandingButton;
    EditText mTaxEdit;
    String tax;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_tip);

        mPoorButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.poor_button);
        mAverageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.average_button);
        mGoodButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.good_button);
        mOutstandingButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.outstanding_button);
        mTaxEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_tax);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        tax = mTaxEdit.getText().toString();

        mPoorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent.putExtra("tax_percentage", tax);
                intent.putExtra("tip_percentage", 8.0);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mAverageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent.putExtra("tax_percentage", tax);
                intent.putExtra("tip_percentage", 10.00);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mGoodButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent.putExtra("tax_percentage", tax);
                intent.putExtra("tip_percentage", 15.00);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mOutstandingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent.putExtra("tax_percentage", tax);
                intent.putExtra("tip_percentage", 20.0);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }


}
```

Someone can help with this problem.

If you need the .xml with the layouts let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to start your second activity a default launcher activity?? or start first activity depending on an value from second activity??

Comment: @VinCardoso: Use startActivityForResult(intent) and get back result in onActivityResult()

Comment: @sur007 I Want a start the first activity depending on values from second activity!

Comment: @kevz How i use this function?

Comment: @VinCardoso go through this link once http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/12204/onactivityresult-android-tutorial/